# R: Importing vector graphics to a plot - Cannot get grImport to work

Tags: r

I am trying to use the grImport package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/index.html) to import an external vector image into an R plot, e.g. I take this picture:

[image: drawing]

and then I convert to ps using the convert of ImageMagick:

```
convert crashed.jpg crashed.ps
```

I the start R and issue the following commands:

```
R> library("grImport")
R> PostScriptTrace("crashed.ps", "crashed.xml")
R> myPic = readPicture("crashed.xml")
R> grid.picture(myPic)
```

and then according to http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/vignettes/import.pdf the image is supposed to be displayed. But all I get is an empty plot popping up!

```
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)
```

Comment: Have you looked in the XML file? Or considered posting it? Have you tried a simpler image - maybe make one with ImageMagick like this `convert -size 400x400 xc:blue -draw "rectangle 10,10 200,200" test.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell : Thanks for reply. If I make a file `test.png` as suggested and then use the same command as stated above, I still get the empty plot popping up. The following is the content of the resulting `test.xml` file: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>

<picture version='3' xmlns:rgml='http://r-project.org/RGML' source='test.ps' date='2015-04-28 16:25:19' creator='R (3.1.3)' >

<summary count='0' ymax='-99999' ymin='99999' xmax='-99999' xmin='99999'/>

</picture>
`. I am not experienced with the XML format.

Comment: I'm no expert on XML either but that doesn't appear to contain any of the rectangles ImageMagick created...

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly old question. Given that it's still unanswered, I thought I'd share some modern tools for incorporating external graphics into R plots.

### Preliminaries

Using ImageMagick or equivalent, convert the source `.jpg` to `.pdf`. On Linux, this is done using `convert crashed.jpg crashed.pdf`. We will also use the following base plot throughout the answer:

```
library( ggplot2 )
g0 <- ggplot( mtcars, aes(disp, mpg) ) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

### Importing the image as a plot panel using [grImport2](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/grImport2/index.html)

We first use `grConvert` to convert the .pdf to a .svg, which is then imported and converted to a grob object.

```
grConvert::convertPicture( "crashed.pdf", "crashed.svg" )
p <- grImport2::readPicture( "crashed.svg" )
g <- grImport2::pictureGrob( p )
gridExtra::grid.arrange( g0, g, nrow=1 )
```

[image]

### Overlaying the image on top of an existing plot using [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html)

Unlike the above, this solution works directly with the .jpg:

```
## Ensure magick is installed for draw_image()
if(!require("magick")) install.packages( "magick" )
cowplot::ggdraw(g0) + cowplot::draw_image("crashed.jpg", x=0.25, y=0.25, scale=0.25)
```

[image]

### Using the image as a plot element with the help of [egg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html)

This approach also works directly with the .jpg. We load the image and populate a new column in `mtcars` with the resulting object. The column can then be provided to `geom_custom()` in a standard ggplot fashion:

```
mtcars$img <- list(jpeg::readJPEG( "crashed.jpg" ))
g0 + egg::geom_custom( data=mtcars, aes(data=img), grob_fun=grid::rasterGrob,
                      fun_params = list(height=unit(1,"lines")) )
```

[image]